# Google Chrome undoes my bookmark changes

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-sync

I'm trying to do various edits in my bookmarks but each time I make a change, after 10 or 15 seconds all the changes are reversed. I tried to sort the bookmarks and add some bookmarks to certain folders by drag and drop, but after a few seconds everything is returned to its place.

Does anybody know why this is happening ?

Comment: You have multiple devices syncing your bookmarks I suggest logging out of all clients making your change the logging back in

Comment: @Ramhound - You seem to make a habit of posting comments that IMO could be answers.

Comment: @Nifle The comment I made isn't descriptive enough and this would be a very low quality answer.  Anyone is free to answer the question now they know that was the problem.  However a two sentence answer isn't helpful in my opinion though.